# How do I translate this SQL query to Lambda or LINQ that uses (where is null)

Tags: c#, sql, lambda

I've been trying to modify some rows of data in SQL to test in my application and I've noticed my query in Lambda brings back 0 rows when I am expecting 2387 row. The source of the problem is I am using parenthesis in a WHERE clause in SQL to look at some null values. This is the SQL query:

**SQL**

```
-- THIS WORKS!
select * from vwAppsWithIssues
   where fld1stCheckAllocatedTo = 'nicholasg' and fldStage = 1
   and (fldStopStartDate is null or fldStopEndDate is not null)

-- The query was originally this (doesn't return rows)
  select * from vwAppsWithIssues
  where fld1stCheckAllocatedTo = 'nicholasg' and fldStage = 1
  and (fldStopStartDate = null or fldStopEndDate <> null)
```

**LAMBDA query that returns 0 rows**

```
public static int GetApplicationsFirstCount(string UserId)
        {
            try
            {
                using (IME_CheckOffEntities IME_CheckOffEntities = new IME_CheckOffEntities())
                {
                    return IME_CheckOffEntities.vwAppsWithIssues
                         .Where(a => a.fld1stCheckAllocatedTo == UserId && a.fldStage == 1 && (a.fldStopStartDate == null || a.fldStopEndDate != null))
                         .ToList().Count;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

**Update**

Using LINQPad I have written this expression:

```
VwAppsWithIssues
.Where (v => v.Fld1stCheckAllocatedTo == "nicholasg"
&& v.FldStage == 1 
&& (v.FldStopStartDate == null || v.FldStopEndDate != null)).Count()
```

that generates this sql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [vwAppsWithIssues] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[fld1stCheckAllocatedTo] = @p0) AND ([t0].[fldStage] = @p1) AND (([t0].[fldStopStartDate] IS NULL) OR ([t0].[fldStopEndDate] IS NOT NULL))
```

So now that I have some lambda that I think will work, I simply copy it to visual studio.

```
  var count = IME_CheckOffEntities.vwAppsWithIssues
      .Where(v => v.fld1stCheckAllocatedTo == "nicholasg" && v.fldStage == 1 && (v.fldStopStartDate == null || v.fldStopEndDate != null)).Count();
```

It still returns only 0 rows?! I am passing in the right userId in C# as well.

My count in c# also returns 0 rows. Any idea how I can rewrite this C# query?

Comment: Capture the SQL that the C# app executed using SQL Profiler.

Comment: Try to split your query in 2 distinct queries. First check for the == null && != null condition then apply the other condition. So that you can see if there is a problem with your expression or not

Comment: Your database null value, *may* be translated in some default value by sql driver you use, so property value may not be a null.

Comment: As suggested, check the sql generated by the query. Assign the result to the query to a variable then just inspect the variable to get the sql.

Comment: I'll look into SQL Profiler.

Comment: linqpad is great for this kind of exploration

Comment: @tschmit007 How would I use linqpad to translate SQL into LINQ?

Comment: not to translate but to check generated sql

Comment: what does `count.Dump();` prints in LingPad ?

Comment: trivial but.... are you sure of yout connection string ? Are'nt you testing on an empty database ?

Comment: I'm such an idiot, because my entity framework is in another project I have been copying and pasting the connection strings from app.config to web.config in my solution. Your comment made me check again and I generated a new connection string. Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

from linqpad, on one of my schema

```
from
    f in Files
where
    f.PubDate == null || f.FilingDate != null
select
    f.IdFile
```

is translated as follow

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[idFichier] AS [idFichier]
FROM [dbo].[tableF] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[datePubliF] IS NULL) OR ([Extent1].[dateDepotF] IS NOT NULL)
```

so, in your case, are you, for example, sure of the UserId value ?

Comment: I've updated my post. I copied and pasted my LINQPad query to visual studio and I am still getting 0 rows.